# How can I install CudNN to ububntu 18.04? I cant get permissson from cuda.h 't 's read only and I cant convert it

Tags: ubuntu, chmod, cudnn

I am trying to copy following files into the `CUDA` Toolkit directory, and change the file permissions. However I couldn't get permission allow `CUDA`. I tried many methods like `chmod` but it does not work for ubuntu 18.04.

```
$ sudo cp cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/include
$ sudo cp cuda/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda/lib64
$ sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn*
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason `chmod` do not work is UMASK. Try the command on this way:

```
sudo bash -c "umask=022 chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn*"
```